# 220v 60hz to 220v 120hz Converter

Tags: converter

I have this problem that I need a 120hz power supply whit 220 Volts for my project.
Does any one have any suggestion about haw to doing it or help me whit some schematics like a converter that I can use?!! My main Voltage source is 220v in 60hz.

Comment: Why do you need 120hz power?  If you explain what your project is, there may be easier ways to achieve your actual goal.

Answer (score 2):

How much current / power do you need?

Head over to your closest industrial electrical supplier and ask about Variable Frequency Drives (VFDs).  These will do what you want at probably lower cost than you can build it for.

Comment: Thanks, it was a good point, but actually I have to build it on board for some other parts in one place.

Comment: oh, and my current would be 10A at most.

Comment: You realize that 220V at 10A is over 2000 watts. What size board do you have and do you have any experience with such voltages and power levels?

Comment: Building your own VFD from scratch to handle the power level you are mentioning is a non-trivial task.  I strongly suggest that you look at a commercial offering before deciding to go down that path.

Comment: FWIW - a friend of mine did his Masters thesis on a similar project and was successful - I think that there were a couple of patents that arose out of his research and the technology was licensed to a statup that became quite successful.  But some of his mistakes along the way were pretty darned expensive - high power semiconductors are *expensive* and they fail in spectacular ways.